# Printing unique values of the array in C

Tags: c, arrays, unique, counting

I wrote a function creating a dynamic array of random values and another function creating a new array consisting of unique values of the previous array. The algorithm used counts unique values correctly. However, I faced a problem in printing all values. In the example below the program printed `7 2 12714320 4 5` instead of `7 2 4 5 6` .

This is the program which can be tested:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int *delduplicate(int *v, int size_old, int *size_new);

main()
{
    int n;
    int *norepeat;
    float *results;
    int dim, size_norepeat, i;
    
    int a[7] = {7,2,2,4,5,6,7};
    
    norepeat = delduplicate(a, 7, &size_norepeat);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size_norepeat; i++)
        printf("%d ", norepeat[i]);
}



// delduplicate function
int *delduplicate(int *v, int size_old, int *size_new)
{
    int i, j, k = 1, uniques = 1, repeats, *new_v, temp;
    
    // count the number of unique elements
    for (i = 1; i < size_old; i++)
    {
        int is_unique = 1;
        
        for (j = 0; is_unique && j < i; j++)
        {
            if (v[i] == v[j])
                is_unique = 0;          
        }
        
        if (is_unique)
            uniques++;
    }
    
    *size_new = uniques;
    
    // create new array of unique elements
    new_v = (int*) malloc(*size_new * sizeof(int));
    
    // fill new array with unique elements
    new_v[0] = v[0];
    
    for (i = 1; i < size_old; i++)
    {
        int is_unique = 1;
            
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (v[i] == v[j])
                is_unique = 0;
        }
    
        if (is_unique)
            new_v[k] = v[i];
            k++;
            
    }
    return new_v;
}
```

The problem should be happening here:

```
// fill new array with unique elements
new_v[0] = v[0];

for (i = 1; i < size_old; i++)
{
    int is_unique = 1;
        
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        if (v[i] == v[j])
            is_unique = 0;
    }

    if (is_unique)
        new_v[k] = v[i];
        k++;       
}
```

Comment: what is "the problem" ?

Comment: It does not print all values. In a given example the program prints "7 2 12714320 4 5"

Comment: when the posted code is run through a compiler, a LONG string  of warnings is output.  Starting with:  *untitled1.c:7:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]*   When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnigs.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.

Comment: Note: the last line of the compiler output may be: `Compilation finished successfully.` but that only means the compiler applied some workaround to the problems, not that the correct code was produced.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: OT: regarding: `new_v = (int*) malloc(*size_new * sizeof(int));`  1) the function: `malloc()` expects a parameter of type: `size_t` but `size_new` is an integer.  2)  in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  3) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: OT:  the posted code has a hardcode'ed  value `7` for the number of entries in the array `a[]`  This is error prone.  Much better to let the compiler calculate the value, similar to: `int a[] = {7,2,2,4,5,6,7};`  then obtain the length, like when calling: `delduplicate()` via: `sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a )`

Comment: Thank your for the comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is probably occurring in the following section -

```
if (is_unique)
    new_v[k] = v[i];
    k++;
```

Here you are incrementing k at each iteration. However, you only want to increment it whenever you have found a unique element. `if()` without brackets only considers the first statement. So change it to this -

```
if (is_unique){
    new_v[k] = v[i];
    k++;
}
```

This change should make your program run fine.

---

**Side Note :** If you do not want to use brackets for an `if()` , `for()` , etc, you can separate the statements by commas and use without having the brackets. Like this -

```
if (is_unique)
    new_v[k] = v[i],
    k++;
```

Comment: You are welcome. You could also do it like `new_v[k++] = v[i]`.